# Change the secret used to (un)sign cookies based on request information in Express using cookie-parser

Tags: node.js, express

I want to have a different secret for (un)signing cookies based on the user id from the `req.params`.  I know that the secret is set in the `app.use(cookieParser('secret'))` but how do I change it while the server is running? The secret will be retrieved from the database.

```
app.use(cookieParser('secret'))
//user tries access a resource 
app.get('/:id',(req,res) => {
    const expectedID = req.params.id
    //based on the url id find the user specific secret on the database
    console.log(req.signedCookies)

    res.cookie('ID','user1', params)
    res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'public','index.html'))
})
```